# How to decide what to inherit in a module class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Say I want to create a new module to provide encryption/decryption for MySQL. In my module, I might simply have something like this:

```
import mysqlib
import cryptolib

class SqlEncryption:

    def encrypt(foo):
        cryptolib.encrypt(foo)

    def decrypt(bar)
        cryptolib.decrypt(bar)
```

but of course I could inherit from the crypto and/or sql libs:

```
class SqliteEncryption(mysqlib, cryptolib):
```

of course using `super` and everything. I usually inherit but this is the first time I've had to wonder if I should inherit from the sql lib, the crypto lib, or both. How should one decide or does it not matter since I'm not actually needing to access anything in those two modules that isn't already exposed in their APIs?

Comment: It definitely doesn't make sense to inherit from a module. I think you've misunderstood how modules and/or inheritance work.

Comment: Deciding what module to inherit from is like deciding what flavor of soup to wear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particularly using any of the methods or classes from the super library directly in your code, you may not have to import it at all.